# Autocomplete in google maps places throws error TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'a[zG]("placeholder")')

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am struggling with this more than I should.

I am creating a simple search map feature, but autocomplete throws me not-so-descriptive error: TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'azG')

I am initialising my map in bootstrap modal on modal.s.shown event.

Here is the Javascript:

```
$('#map-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    //picking up data attributes from the image that initialised the modal
    var image = $(e.relatedTarget);
    map_lat = $(image).data('lat');
    map_lng = $(image).data('lng');

    //passing the data to a initialise map function
    initialiseModalMap(map_lat,map_lng);

    //add autocomplete
    var input = $('#start-point');
    var options = {
        types: ['geocode']
    };
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
       console.log('changed');
    });
});
```

But as soon as the event shown.bs.modal is fired, I get the following error in the console:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'a[zG]("placeholder")')
```

And autocomplete is never executed, and before autocomplete chunk of code, everything was fine.

What am I missing?

If you need more info please do ask.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I switched to vanilla javascript to get the input element, error is not thrown

so instead

```
var input = $('#start-point');
```

I put

```
var input = document.getElementById('start-point');
```

But the dropdown of autocomplete is not rendered, but i guess that is a whole different question

Comment: Good answer. The API expects a reference to a DOM element, while jQuery returns a jQuery object. $("#start-point").get(0) allows you to use jQuery to get access to the raw DOM object.